# Android Webview with child at bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout, webview

I've been searching both Google and stackoverflow for a while now and haven't found anything answering my question.

I'm wondering about putting a `LinearLayout` (with no specific known height in pixels) at the bottom of a `WebView`. This `LinearLayout` will later be populated with a fragment containing comments for the article displayed in the `WebView`.

The issue of the problem is that the `WebView` is almost always larger than the screen so the user has to scroll to read the full article. At the bottom of the scrolling I want the `CommentsFragment` to be inserted (through the `LinearLayout`, it takes a few parameters so it can't be loaded directly from the XML).

I've tried a bunch of solutions but all of them make the `LinearLayout` stick to the bottom of the layout the all time, not on the bottom of the `WebView`.

My current code is the following, of course not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/article_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: do u want that comments frgament will be below the webview ?

Comment: Yes correct, i havent solved it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working after a few rounds. The solution was using a ScrollView then inside that a relativelayout mirroring @Karan_rana's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/article_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi sorry no this doesn't work either. Can you please post here a working example of this code? You don't have to use fragments the comment, just make it a fixed height. Thanks for your post though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the comments fragment below web view then you can try as following and tell me if it works for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/article_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_above="@id/comments_container"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comments_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, no sorry it doesn't work, it's stuck at the bottom of the screen, not at the bottom of the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure to have `layout_height="wrap_content"` in your WebView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/article_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/comments_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have to go now but will try this later. I think there will be an issue with scrolling horizontally in webview if the images are e.g. too wide but I will try it.

Comment: This solution won't fix your WebView's horizontal scrolling problem, for that maybe try some CSS magic to make it fit if you control the input

Comment: Hi again, this doesn't work either sorry, it just made a really long scrollview with nothing at the bottom.